# Trying to write UDF to create valuelist from ORM object

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am trying to write a function that will run just like the valuelist() function for cfquery.  Here is my code:

```
    links = entityload('press_releases_lnk',{prp_pr_id=article.getpr_id()});

function ormvaluelist(object,colname){
    retrnstr = '';
    for(mynum=1;mynum<=arraylen(object);mynum++){
        myvalue = object[mynum].getcolname();
        retrnstr = retrnstr&myvalue&',';
    }
    return retrnstr;
}

catlist=ormvaluelist(links,'prp_product_cat');
```

The problem is getting "getcolname" to use the variable that I pass in as the column name.  I'm sure I am just missing something simple.

Thanks

Comment: `myvalue = object[mynum][colname]; myvalue=myvalue();` ?

Comment: @Peter - is this an example of a closure?

Comment: No. It's a workaround for Adobe being unable to implement the `myvalue = object[mynum][colname]()` syntax that the rest of the world uses. (Which may or not be what the OP is after). A closure is a function that "encloses" its state - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)

Comment: myvalue is a variable that initially holds a function. What would be the proper term for that?

Comment: I'd call it "a variable". Or maybe "a variable that holds a function". :P Assigning functions to variables isn't doing anything special, and has been possible since CFMX (if not before).

Comment: When doing `a = function(){...}` the bit on the right of the `=` is a "function expression" and is also called an "anonymous function" (because it has no name), and in many languages it's _also_ a closure (because it does magic with states) - but this is entirely different to what's going on above.

Comment: @PeterBoughton that's not how orm entity works.  You don't just go `object[mynum][colname]`, you need to call the setter.

Comment: Then it should be `object[mynum]['get#colname#']` instead of evaluate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you get away with using `ormExecuteQuery("select #column# from #entityName#")`?  It'll return an array and you can convert the array into a list using `arrayToList()`.

Notice that `colname` should really be property name in entity.  If you really meant column name in db, then use good the old `<cfquery>`, and `valueList()`.

CF10:

```
myvalue = invoke(object[mynum], "get#colname#");
```

CF9 or below if you have to use cfscript:

```
myvalue = evaluate("object[mynum].get#colname#()");
```

Idea from @PeterBoughton, I used it before and it may work for you, or not, try it:

```
getterFunction = object[mynum]['get#colname#'];
myvalue = getterFunction();
```

Otherwise, use CFML:

```
<cfinvoke component="#object[mynum]#" method="get#colname#"
          returnVariable="myvalue">
```

Don't forget there's `listAppend()`, so you don't have to worry about the extra `,` at the end of your return list.  And var scope your variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I used the CF10 solution and it works great.  You saved my hours of work.  Thanks again.

Comment: also, u can try a `for-in` loop for array you like. :)